# Unable to get wifi SSID in Huawei phone

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, ssid, huawei-mobile-services

I am working on the android app in which I need to get the connected WIFI info like SSID of it.
code is working perfectly on other android phone but not on Huawei it giving me <"unknown ssid">.

I already have runtime permission

```
fun getWifiInfo(context: Context): Connection? {
     if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         var ssid = ""
         var bssid = ""
         var isConnected = false
         val wifiManager = context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
         val wifiInfo = wifiManager.connectionInfo

    // Android version is Nougat OR Marshmallow
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

        if (wifiInfo.supplicantState == SupplicantState.COMPLETED) {
            ssid = wifiInfo.ssid
        }
    } else {
        if (wifiInfo.supplicantState == SupplicantState.COMPLETED) {
            ssid = wifiInfo.ssid
            bssid= wifiInfo.bssid
            if (ssid.startsWith("\"") && ssid.endsWith("\"")) {
                ssid = wifiInfo.ssid.replace("SSID: ", "").replace("\"", "");
            }
            print("SSID: $ssid")
            isConnected = true
        }
    }
         return Connection(ssid,isConnected,bssid) // creating new object.
     } else {
         return null
     }
}
```

Comment: What is the phone model? What's version. There are many questions.

Comment: Huawei P10
on different phones, My cod is working fine even on other Huawei phones. but not on Huawei P10